# PDO sql delete with multiple conditions

Tags: php, sql, pdo

This is what I tried:

```
$query="DELETE FROM network_friend WHERE friend_request = :usrfriend AND friend = :isfriend UNION DELETE FROM network_friend WHERE friend_request = :friend_request AND friend = :friendisfriend";
```

---

## I have the column structure

[image: db]

same structure instead of

```
friend1 friend2 friend1
```

could be like

```
friend2 friend1 friend2
```

How to delete  case if columns: **friend_request** OR **friend_is_friend** Is the same user and  **friend** column is the user I want to delete?

something like `"DELETE FROM table WHERE friend = :user1 AND friend_request = :user2 AND friend_is_friend = :user2"`

or also the inverse

`"DELETE FROM table WHERE friend = :user2 AND friend_request = :user1 AND friend_is_friend = :user1"`

The problem is i need delete case `user1 = friend_request` and `user1 friend_is_friend` AND ALSO `friend = user2` the inverse could also be in the place of `user 1 user 2` and in the place of `user 2 user 1`

How to delete with multiple conditions and make this into single statement?

Comment: `UNION` makes no sense with `DELETE`.

Comment: Please create an [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
DELETE nf FROM network_friend nf
    WHERE (friend_request = :usrfriend AND friend = :isfriend) OR
          (friend_request = :friend_request AND friend = :friendisfriend)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: what does `DELETE nf ` do?

Comment: @Developer . . . That says to delete from `nf` which is the alias for `network_friend`.

Comment: I let it as you answered and it worked, should I change nf to network_friend or let as it's?

Comment: I think there is no problem, I just didn't knew I could declare a table as alias

Answer (score 0):

I think it is =D

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM network_friend WHERE friend_request = friend_is_friend AND friend = :user_you_want_to_delete';
```